# Match embedded Documents by Regular expression with Mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, mongoengine

I have a list of Document, each containing 50(this could vary) EmbeddedDocument. Now I want to query all the EmbeddedDocument(across all the Document) containing id which starts with a certain pattern.

```
class Container(Document):
    list = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Data)

class Data(EmbeddedDocument):
    id=StringField(required=True, primary_key=True)
```

Now the query(or something like startswith) will be on 'id' of Data.

Comment: Please do not suggest looking at every embedded document in all the document. we cannot afford O(m*n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an embedded field then you would need both the embedded syntax using a ["double underscore"](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#filtering-queries) `__` to denote the field as compared to native ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) as well as the [`startswith`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#string-queries) or `istartswith` modifier for the string:

```
Container.objects(list__id__startswith="AAA")
```

Else if you need a "real" regular expression rather than the shortcuts allowed, then you can use the [`__raw__`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#raw-queries) modifier with a "raw" MongoDB syntax query:

```
Container.objects(__raw__={ "list.id": ,re.compile('^AAA', re.IGNORECASE) })
```

Or possibly `"list._id"` depending on how the field names have been told to serialize for the embedded object.

Either way essentially offloads the query to the database where it can use it's features to determine a match.

There is of course a basic `mongoengine` limitation that there is no way possible to simply project the matched array element(s). This is all about how the class data is read and instantiated.

You can return "raw python objects" as an alternate the the implemented classes, using the `.aggregate()` method:

```
Container._get_collection().aggregate({
    { "$match": { "list.id": ,re.compile('^AAA', re.IGNORECASE) } },
    { "$unwind": "$list" },
    { "$match": { "list.id": ,re.compile('^AAA', re.IGNORECASE) } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "list": { "$push": "$list" }
    }}
])
```

So no longer the same `class` defined, but there is also nothing to stop you from feeding that raw data to instantiate a new object of the required class if you need to.

Comment: I did Container.objects(list__id__startswith="AAA"), it returns all the Container if any of its embedded doc matches the pattern. So shall we look at each of the embedded doc in each container to make a list of Data

Comment: @KumarNitin That is a `mongoengine` limitation in that it will not alter the document returned to just return the matched array element. The same "basically" applies to MongoDB itself, however in raw form you can use "projection" to return the matched "element" ( singular ). MongoEngine itself will not do it as first class objects, but `.aggregate()` can return a "plain" object with just the matching "element(s)".

Comment: Will it impact the performance if we do this operation on million embedded document(each Document containing 50/100 EmbeddedDocument )?

Comment: @KumarNitin The general query is very little as MongoDB is pretty smart about this. If you really need to only filter out just the matched array items only, I added an example using `.aggregate()` where there are other alternatives to the `$unwind` used there for processing, but not really an option when using a regular expression for the match. `$unwind` can add overhead as it essentially "explodes" the array to dicreet documents so other operations can be performed. 50-100 is fairly small, and it's more about the overall matches as to how big the impact is.

Comment: It was really helpful. Thanks mate!